# Open fileless source code document in code editor from VS 2010 extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a Visual Studio 2010 extension using the VS 2010 SDK SP1 that will open source code files in the code editor.  The extension is a ToolWindow that is docked where the Solution Explorer is located.

The extension consumes a WCF service where it retrieves the source code files and displays the hierarchy in a TreeView.  When the code file is double clicked, it should load the associated source into the code editor window much like the Solution Explorer does.

I have been reading about VS extension and DTE automation for a while now and have made very little progress.  It seems that I am able to access already opened or active WpfTextViews without a problem, but I do not understand how to open a new TextView into the document area of the IDE.  Keep in mind that these are not actual source code files saved on the disk, but rather they are retrieved from the WCF service and stored in memory.

Could anyone provide an example or give me some guidance on how to implement this please?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a temporary file, filling it with the source code and load that temp file? (Or creating  new temp file, adding it to the IDE and then insert your source code there...)

Maybe that's not exactly what you wanted but it'll do the trick...

*(If you create a new file in VS (File -> New...), VS will create a temp file as well and ask for the "correct" location when you want to save the file for the first time.)*

Comment: I thought about doing that but I couldn't figure out what code to use to actually get it to work.  Part of the problem is that VS doesn't like to open files that are not part of a solution heirarchy, so it wants you to specify the project or solution the file belongs to. If the file is not opened as part of a project you dont get any benefits of intellisense or any other useful code editor features.  I'm wondering if there is a way to reference libraries or dlls that intellisense can use to build its database with.  If you have any example code for how to open a code window please share it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a cache of the whole source tree on the local drive and then just load the solution from file instead of from memory?